# Is it possible to loop over an html structure and display it multiple time using jQuery and json

Tags: jquery, json, each

I am trying to create a loop over json content using jquery and append the content as structured html.  With the example code below, I would just want to plug the jason in where I would need it.  My issue is that I can't get the loop to recreate the html structure depending on how many reviews there are.

An example: If I have three reviews, I want to loop over those reviews and display three separate html structures for the content.

Does anyone know is this is possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: 'http:this-is-a-url-with-json-in-it.com',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
        if ( data.length == 0 ) {
            alert('nothing in it');
        } else {
            $(data.Results).each(function(index,element){
                $('.reviewContentBox').html(
                    '<div class="col-md-2 pull-left author_details">' +
                        '<h5>'+ 'VeryLongUserNameHere' + '</h5>' +
                        '<h5>' + '<img src="#imgAssetURL#blue_ribbon.png" alt="">' + 'TOP 1000 CONTRIBUTOR' + '</h5>' +
                        '<em class="bio">' + 'Age:' + 'over' + '65' + 'Gender:' + 'Female' + '</em>' + 
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-md-10 pull-left border_left">' +
                        '<div class="col-md-9">' +
                            '<div class="ratings">' + '<img src="#imgAssetURL#stars_large.png" alt="">' + '<em>' + '4' + '</em>' + '</div>' +
                            '<h4>' + 'Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.' + '</h4>' +
                            '<em class="date">' + 'Date 00, 2013' + '</em>' +
                            '<p>' + element.ReviewText + '</p>' +

                            '<strong>' + 'Cons:' + '</strong>' + 'Nisi erat porttitor ligula.' + '</p>' +
                            '<div class="found_helpful">' + '<em class="count">' + '147 of 150 people found the following review helpful' + '</em>' +
                                '<ul>' +
                                    '<li>' + '<a href="##">' + '<img src="#imgAssetURL#fb_btn.png" alt="">' + '</a>' + '</li>' +
                                    '<li>' + '<a href="##" class="btn_small">' + '<img src="#imgAssetURL#right_icon.png" alt="">' + 'helpful' + '<span class="no">' + '0' + '</span>' + '</a>' + '</li>' +
                                    '<li>' + '<a href="##" class="btn_small">' + '<img src="#imgAssetURL#wrong_icon.png" alt="">' + 'unhelpful' + '<span class="no">' + '0' + '</span>' + '</a>' + '</li>' +
                                    '<li>' + '<a href="##">' + '<img src="#imgAssetURL#no_icon.png" alt="">' + '</a>' + '</li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-md-3 fit_guide">' +
                            '<ul>' +
                                '<li>' +
                                    '<div class="bar">' + '<span class="drag">' + '</span>' + '</div>' +
                                    '<span class="pull-left">' + 'Runs Small' + '</span>' + '<span class="pull-right">' + 'Runs Big' + '</span>' +
                                '</li>' +
                                '<li>' +
                                    '<div class="bar">' + '<span class="drag">' + '</span>' + '</div>' +
                                    '<span class="pull-left">' + 'Runs Small' + '</span>' + '<span class="pull-right">' + 'Runs Big' + '</span>' +
                                '</li>' +
                            '</ul>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
                );

            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: At the beginning of the method set the `$('.reviewContentBox').html("")` empty and then use `append` instead of `html` which will add the code instead of change it, just a recommendation but if this was what you were looking for tell me to make it an answer

Answer (score 0):

After going through Mark E solution in the comment above, I realized all I needed to do was to was to replace the .html() with .append().  The reason for this is that the .html() was overwriting the content on every loop where append adds it on.  Thank you Mark for the help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://put-your-url-here',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
        if ( data.length == 0 ) {
            alert('nothing in it');
        } else {

            $(data.Results).each(function(index,element){
                $('.reviewContentBox').append(
                    '<div class="col-md-2 pull-left author_details">' +
                        '<h5>'+ 'VeryLongUserNameHere' + '</h5>' +
                        '<h5>' + '<img src="#imgAssetURL#blue_ribbon.png" alt="">' + 'TOP 1000 CONTRIBUTOR' + '</h5>' +
                        '<em class="bio">' + 'Age:' + 'over' + '65' + 'Gender:' + 'Female' + '</em>' + 
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-md-10 pull-left border_left">' +
                        '<div class="col-md-9">' +
                            '<div class="ratings">' + '<img src="#imgAssetURL#stars_large.png" alt="">' + '<em>' + '4' + '</em>' + '</div>' +
                            '<h4>' + element.Title + '</h4>' +
                            '<em class="date">' + moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY' , element.LastModificationTime) + '</em>' +
                            '<p>' + element.ReviewText + '</p>' +

                            '<strong>' + 'Cons:' + '</strong>' + element.Cons + '</p>' +
                            '<div class="found_helpful">' + '<em class="count">' + '147 of 150 people found the following review helpful' + '</em>' +
                                '<ul>' +
                                    '<li>' + '<a href="##">' + '<img src="#imgAssetURL#fb_btn.png" alt="">' + '</a>' + '</li>' +
                                    '<li>' + '<a href="##" class="btn_small">' + '<img src="#imgAssetURL#right_icon.png" alt="">' + 'helpful' + '<span class="no">' + '0' + '</span>' + '</a>' + '</li>' +
                                    '<li>' + '<a href="##" class="btn_small">' + '<img src="#imgAssetURL#wrong_icon.png" alt="">' + 'unhelpful' + '<span class="no">' + '0' + '</span>' + '</a>' + '</li>' +
                                    '<li>' + '<a href="##">' + '<img src="#imgAssetURL#no_icon.png" alt="">' + '</a>' + '</li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="col-md-3 fit_guide">' +
                            '<ul>' +
                                '<li>' +
                                    '<div class="bar">' + '<span class="drag">' + '</span>' + '</div>' +
                                    '<span class="pull-left">' + 'Runs Small' + '</span>' + '<span class="pull-right">' + 'Runs Big' + '</span>' +
                                '</li>' +
                                '<li>' +
                                    '<div class="bar">' + '<span class="drag">' + '</span>' + '</div>' +
                                    '<span class="pull-left">' + 'Runs Small' + '</span>' + '<span class="pull-right">' + 'Runs Big' + '</span>' +
                                '</li>' +
                            '</ul>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
                );

            });
        }
    }
});
```